# Sequel join: ".id" is returning the id of the the other table

Tags: ruby, join, sequel, ramaze

I have a Ruby app which uses Ramaze and Sequel.

I have the classes `Tag` and `Tagging` which have this relationship:

```
class Tag < Sequel::Model
  one_to_many  :taggings, :class => 'Thoth::Tagging'

class Tagging < Sequel::Model(:taggings)
  many_to_one :tag, :class => 'Thoth::Tag'
```

I want to return a list of tags in order of popularity, the ones that have the most taggings (filtering out any that have less than three taggings).  I'm doing that this way:

```
tags = .left_outer_join(:taggings, :tag_id => :id).group(:tag_id).having("count(*) > 2").order("count(*) desc").all
```

This does return what seem to be tag objects, but when I call `.id` on them, I get the id of a tagging that points to the tag, rather than the tag itself.

On closer inspection, the results are quite different from a regular find:

```
> tag_regular = Tag[2]
=> #<Thoth::Tag @values={:title=>nil, :position=>nil, :parent_id=>1, :name=>"academic", :id=>2}>

> tag_from_join = Tag.join(:taggings, :tag_id => :id).group(:tag_id).having("count(*) > 2").order("count(*) desc").all.select{|tag| tag.name == "academic"}.first
=> #<Thoth::Tag @values={:tag_id=>2, :post_id=>5, :title=>nil, :position=>nil, :parent_id=>1, :name=>"academic", :id=>1611, :created_at=>nil}>
```

In both cases I get a Thoth::Tag, but the values are quite different, based on the different fields in the join I suppose.

All I actually need to do is get a list of regular tag objects sorted by the number of taggings, but in an efficient single-query way.  Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

The default selection is `*`, so you are selecting columns from both `tags` and `taggings`.  If you have an `id` column in both tables, because Sequel returns records as a hash keyed by column name, columns in the `taggings` table will override columns with the same name in the `tags` table.

If you only want the columns from `tags`, add `select_all(:tags)` to the dataset.

The Sequel master branch has a `table_select` plugin that will handle this situation by default.